# Derivation of one-form/vector equation in Carroll confusion

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields

I don't understand the derivation of Equation 2.14$$\mathrm{d}f\left(\frac{d}{d\lambda}\right)=\frac{df}{d\lambda} \tag{2.14}$$
 in Carroll's Lecture Notes on General Relativity (http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll2.html). He says the one-form $\mathrm{d}f$ is the gradient of a function $f$ and that the action of the one-form $\mathrm{d}f$ “on a vector $\frac{d}{d\lambda}$ is exactly the directional derivative of the function.” Schutz (Geometrical Methods of Mathematical Physics, p53) gives the same equation, but says it defines the gradient one-form $\mathrm{d}f$. Is the equation a definition or can it be derived in some way? I'm pretty much a beginner trying to learn this stuff and probably feel more at ease with component notation, such as $\frac{d}{d\lambda}=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}$ for a tangent vector and $\mathrm{d}f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\nu}}dx^{\nu}$ for a one-form (hope I've got those right).

Can I just add that if I assume $\mathrm{\mathrm{d}x^{i}}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}\right)=\delta_{j}^{i}$ I can indeed derive the equation. However, a few pages further on (p56) Schutz appears to derive $\mathrm{\mathrm{d}x^{i}}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}\right)=\delta_{j}^{i}$ from $\mathrm{d}f\left(\frac{d}{d\lambda}\right)=\frac{df}{d\lambda}$. That's what I find puzzling. Is there an explanation/derivation of $\mathrm{d}f\left(\frac{d}{d\lambda}\right)=\frac{df}{d\lambda}$ without the assumption of $\mathrm{\mathrm{d}x^{i}}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}\right)=\delta_{j}^{i}$?

Comment: If you plug your component notation (as definitions) in there, the equation is also true, so it is true by definition. I'm not sure what exactly your question is.

Comment: I've edited my question to try to make my confusion clearer.

Comment: So to speak....

Comment: If you can see it, here's the link to p56 of the Schutz book: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HAPMB2e643kC&pg=PA53&dq=%22one-form%22+vector+gradient+%22directional+derivative%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22naturally%2C%20all%20these%22&f=false

Comment: Perhaps it's a good idea for you to pick up a book on differential geometry if you're looking for a more thorough exposition of this issue. I recommend Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds"; he has a chapter about this stuff somewhere early in the book. Note, however, that this will be significantly time consuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need $dx^i \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right) = \delta^i_j$ to derive the relation.

The easiest way to see this is working backwards from the regular expression for $\frac{df}{d\lambda}(x)$. If we denote the tangent vector as $t^\mu(x) = \frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}$, we have:
$$
\frac{df}{d\lambda}(x) = t^\mu(x) \partial_\mu f(x) = df(t(x)) = df\left(\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\right) = \left(df \frac{d}{d\lambda} \right)(x) 
$$

where in the last equality above the tangent vector $t(x)$ is regarded as a vector application $t = \frac{d}{d\lambda}$. So technically $\frac{df}{d\lambda} = df \circ \frac{d}{d\lambda} = df\left( \frac{d}{d\lambda}\right)$.

Comment: Apologies for my limited (high school) maths, but what's the difference between my $\frac{df}{d\lambda}$ and your $\frac{df}{d\lambda}\left(x\right)$? Thanks.

Comment: $\frac{df}{d\lambda}$ is a function, as in "member of a function space", while $\frac{df}{d\lambda}(x)$ is its value at $x$. Also, notice that the text uses $\frac{d}{d\lambda} = t^\mu\partial_\mu$ as an application on functions $f$ that produces a function $\frac{df}{d\lambda}$, while $t=\frac{d}{d\lambda}$ acts on coordinate vectors $x$ and produces a tangent vector t(x). I guess this slight abuse of notation is the main source of confusion: just make sure to keep track of the correct domain in each case.

Comment: So I need to think of everything in your derivation being evaluated at a point $x$? Are you saying $\partial_{\mu}f(x)=df$? I can't see why that is. Doesn't $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}dx^{\mu}$?

Comment: Yes, everything is evaluated at x, but the conclusion is independent of x. And no, when I wrote $t^\mu\partial_\mu f(x) = df(t(x))$ I meant df as a 1-form ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Concept): $d_x f(v) = \partial_v f(x) = v^\mu\partial_\mu f(x)$. In our case $v = t(x)$ and I omitted the x in $d_x$ for simplicity since it already shows in $t(x)$. The rest is just substituting the explicit form of $t(x)$ and casting it as a vector application on x.

Comment: But isn't $\partial_{v}f(x)=d_{x}f(v)$ the equivalent of $\frac{df}{d\lambda}\left(x\right)= \textrm{d}f\left(\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\right)$, which is equivalent to $\frac{df}{d\lambda}=\textrm{d}f\left(\frac{d}{d\lambda}\right)$, in other words, the very equation we are trying to derive?

Comment: Yes, you just reproduced the one-liner in the answer, provided you do take $v = t(x)$ and make sure that you equate values to values and only then maps to maps. Notice the line above eq.(2.14) in the text: "The canonical example of a one-form is the gradient of a function f, denoted df. Its action on a vector  $ {d\over{d\lambda}}$ is exactly the directional derivative of the function". So yeah, its a trivial example actually.

Comment: Thanks for you patience, but I still don't see (hence the bounty) whether $\mathrm{d}f\left(\frac{d}{d\lambda}\right)=\frac{df}{d\lambda}$ can be derived without assuming $\mathrm{\mathrm{d}x^{i}}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}\right)=\delta_{j}^{i}$. Is that a yes or no? I've just noticed that on page 60 of Gravitation by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler they appear to derive the equation (2.17) from some kind of Taylor series (equation 2.15 on the previous page), but I can't follow that derivation either.

Comment: Ok, I see what's bothering you now. The expression $d_x f(v) = \partial_v f(x)$ is the _definition_ of the one-form $df$ at point $x$, it does not derive from the $df/d\lambda$ relationship you are trying to prove. So the proof goes: "Write the expression of $df/d\lambda$ as a directional derivative along the tangent vector $t$. Then rewrite it the directional derivative using the definition of df at x as applied to vector t.

Comment: Rewrite the components of t as derivatives of coordinates along the curve parametrized by lambda, and lastly interpret these derivatives (and t) as components of a vector application acting at point t". This is exactly what you said in a comment above, but I think the confusion is not realizing that the starting step is an independent definition.

Comment: As for eq.(2.17) in Misner, Thorne, Wheeler, it is the same definition for $df$. The confusion with $df$ is the following. The derivative of a function along a given direction $v$ is usually interpreted as a function of the point $x$ where it is calculated, as in $\partial_v f(x)$. But, let's fix $x$ and look at the partial derivative as a function of the direction vector $v$: it turns out that it is linear in $v$, therefore it is a linear functional.

Comment: Moreover, it can always be expressed as a linear combination involving the components of $v$ and the partial derivatives of f along the coordinate axes. In fact, it is the inner product of the gradient of $f$ and $v$, and is entirely defined by the gradient vector! If we know the gradient vector at every $x$, we know $f$'s derivatives along any direction $v$. Therefore we can simply redefine $\partial_v f(x)$ as a linear functional (a one-form) on the space of $v$'s, which we relabel $d_xf(v)$ and call "the derivative of f". Misner et al explain the same thing in slightly different language.

Comment: So when you write $d_{x}f(v)=\partial_{v}f(x)$ you mean the one-form $d_{x}f$ acting on the vector $v$ equals the derivative of $f$ with respect to $\lambda$ at position $x$? So the two sets of brackets mean different things. In the case of $\left(v\right)$, they mean “acting on”, and in the case of $\left(x\right)$, they mean “at the position”?

Comment: Also, (take a deep breath, try to stay calm, do NOT kick the cat!), if the answers to my latest questions are all “yes”, I cannot see much in the way of difference between your definition of a one-form $d_{x}f(v)=\partial_{v}f(x)$
  and my original equation $\mathrm{d}f\left(\frac{d}{d\lambda}\right)=\frac{df}{d\lambda}$. Apart from your definition applying to a particular position $x$.

Comment: Exactly! The confusion comes from the change in the nature of the argument for $df$. What I suggested was just "write the original equation as applied to position x (because $df/d\lambda$ applies to $x$!) so you can recognize familiar concepts. Done." Apart from that, you only need to get around a little abuse of notation regarding $d/d\lambda$ since it is mentioned in another form, with different domain I think, in a preceding paragraph, but that's all really :D

Comment: Equation 2.17 on p60 of Gravitation is $\partial_{v}f=\left\langle \mathrm{d}f,v\right\rangle$ 
  (equivalent, I pray, to $\frac{df}{d\lambda}=\mathrm{d}f\left(\frac{d}{d\lambda}\right)$). As they explain, Eqn 2.17 is itself derived (by applying $\frac{d}{d\lambda}$) from Eqn 2.15 (p59): $f\left(P\right)=f\left(P_{0}\right)+\left\langle \mathrm{d}f,P-P_{0}\right\rangle +\textrm{(non linear terms)}$.

Comment: Could this be a more straightforward answer (at my level) to my question of whether $\frac{df}{d\lambda}=\mathrm{d}f\left(\frac{d}{d\lambda}\right)$ can be derived without assuming $\mathrm{\mathrm{d}x^{i}}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}\right)=\delta_{j}^{i}$? Much further on (p203) they actually use Eqn 2.17 to derive $\mathrm{\mathrm{d}x^{i}}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}\right)=\delta_{j}^{i}$.

Comment: As I said before, Eq. 2.17 of Misner defines the one-form $df$ as a linear functional on vectors $v$. They introduce it in terms of the directional derivative along an arbitrary $v$ and represent it as an inner product (recall that any linear functional can be represented as an inner product). Eq.2.14 in Carroll is only a particular application of this definition to the case when $v = t$, the tangent vector to the $\lambda$ curve. Note that in this case $df$ is not restricted to $t$ alone. It is defined for any $v$, but only when it acts on $t$ does it produce $\frac{df}{d\lambda}$.

Comment: Hmmm, there's a lot to take in here for a plodder like me. You've been very patient. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Welcome and good luck!